# Export File Syntax Highlighting to HTML Using Vim

Tags: vim, export, syntax-highlighting

I wrote a vim syntax highlighting file for a custom file type that I am working and I want to be able to show off my syntax highlighting painlessly by converting my view of the page into an HTML document for others.

My current workflow is basically:

```
vim *.ext
```

and then:

```
:TOhtml
:wq
:n
```

*ad nauseum*

I'm sick of it, I've exported 3 files this way and I've had enough. How can I streamline this using some sort of script?

Comment: You can *almost* use [`:argdo`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#:argdo), like `:argdo TOhtml | wq`. But while that exports the HTML files, they aren’t highlighted, because “while this command is executing, the [Syntax](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#Syntax) [autocommand](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#autocommand) event is disabled [to] speed up editing each file.”

Comment: About [`:TOhtml`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:TOhtml): if you have a file `hello.c` open, `:TOhtml` will open a new buffer editing the nonexistent file `hello.c.html`, containing HTML with syntax-highlighting CSS in it. You can run `:wq` to save that HTML file and close the new window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in *.ext; do vim -c TOhtml -c wqa $i ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a recursive mapping:

```
:map <F2> :TOhtml<enter>:wq<enter>:n<enter><F2>
```

And then press `<F2>`. All your files will be converted automatically.